# How to use ngx-carousel-3d in Angular 7/8?

Tags: angular

So after analysis I found some similar slider for Angular is 'ngx-carousel-3d'. But when I try to use this code I am getting the following error.

./node_modules/ngx-carousel-3d/esm5/ngx-carousel-3d.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'rxjs/Observable' in 'D:\My work\angular\biker-zone\node_modules\ngx-carousel-3d\esm5'.

Or is there any other best 3d carousel for angular 7/8.